# Indirect Addressing in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

Is there a simple method of implementing indirect addressing in VB?

For e.g.

```vb
Dim Name1 as string = "Erik"
Dim Name2 as string = "Name1"
```

Is there a function where lets say if I write below command:

```vb
@Name2 = "Ummi"
```

It will update `Name1` variable to "Ummi".

I have use such function before one industrial company software.

Is there such thing available for normal VB program editor. I am using Visual Studio 2019 for my current application.

Comment: Hard to make sense of this.  But make these variables properties of a class, with backing variables, and the property setter can do anything wonky thing it wants.

Comment: @HansPassant They wanted [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Hi. The variable variables looks exactly what i am looking for. Do you know if this type of function is available for VB ?